# Correct way to query mysql db when moving data from mysql database to .txt file?

Tags: php, mysql

So, I would need to import one specific field (id_number) from mysql database into text file (approved.txt) and every value to to their own line. However, the id_number should be only written to file if the status (id_status) value is 1.

Currently I have:

```
$result = dbquery("SELECT id_number FROM ".APPLICATIONS." 
WHERE id_status = '1' 
INTO OUTFILE 'approved.txt'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n');
```

Could somebody tell me if this is the correct way or is there any better way? Just wondering that there are 3 "-marks, shouldn't there be 4?

Any assistance is appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: Yes, there should be 4 `"`

Comment: or the ones around .APPLICATIONS could be switched to single quotes and then you could do it with 2 `"`

Comment: try `$result = dbquery("SELECT id_number FROM ".APPLICATIONS." WHERE id_status = '1' INTO OUTFILE 'approved.txt' LINES TERMINATED BY \n");`

Comment: I would use `$result = dbquery("SELECT id_number FROM '.APPLICATIONS.' WHERE id_status = '1' INTO OUTFILE 'approved.txt' LINES TERMINATED BY \n");` as suggested by @hellyale

Comment: Thank you for your responses, However when i use the way hellyale suggested i'm receiving this error:                                                                                                       **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''.APPLICATIONS.' WHERE id_status = '1' INTO OUTFILE 'approved.txt' LINES TERMINA' at line 1"**

Answer (score 0):

MySQL query:

```
SELECT id_number  INTO OUTFILE 'approved.txt' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  
FROM table_name  WHERE id_status = '1'
```